# My code isn't updating my database even though no error is popping up

Tags: mysql, vb.net

It doesn't show me any error and tells me its saved. If I replace the `userlable.text` with a real value in the database, it works. But with the `userlable.text` its not working. I have done something similar on another vb.form and it worked so why wouldn't this? It doesn't update in T1Marks on the row where the username is but it says it worked. Any help please?

```
Private Sub Finish1Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Finish1Button.Click

    con = New MySqlConnection

    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Red-grape01;database=math"

    Try

        con.Open()

        Dim Order As String

        Order = "update math.marks set T1Marks='" & MarkLable.Text & "' WHERE Username='" & userlabel.Text & "'"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(Order, con)

        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Saved")

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error")

    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
    ExamTopicSelectionPage.Show()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is any matching data which could be updated?

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in your `Order` variable and open its Text Visualizer then try to Run that Query in your MySQL Workbench (or whatsoever SQL IDE you have) and see if it does any work. You can see if it really updates any records at all.

Comment: `Dim rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: 1. Use parameterized queries, unless you want to be exposed to Sql injection attacks. 2. Don't use `executeReader`, use `ExecuteNonQuery`.